# Mapr using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapr

I am new to Hadoop, Mapr and Pivotal. I have written java  code to write into pivotal but facing issue while writing into Mapr.

```
  public class HadoopFileSystemManager {
        private String url;
        public void writeFile(String filePath,String data) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
            Path fPath = new Path(filePath);
            String url = url = "hdfs://"+ip+":"+"8020";
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(url),new Configuration());
            System.out.println(fs.getWorkingDirectory());
            FSDataOutputStream writeStream = fs.create(fPath);
            writeStream.writeChars(data);
            writeStream.close();
        }

    }
```

This code works fine with pivoatal but fails with Mapr.

For Mapr i am using port = 7222. 
I am getting the following error 
"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Please let me know if am using the right port or anything needs to be changed in the code specific to Mapr.

I have stopped the iptables.

Any info is much appreciated.

Thanks

## Heading

Comment: How are you running the java program. From terminal?

Comment: Running  Junit test cases :
 @Test
    public void writeFileTest3() {
 
        HadoopFileSystemManager fs = new HadoopFileSystemManager();
        try {
            fs.writeFile("/tmp/dummy","This is the test String");
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
            assertEquals(0,1);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. But make sure you have MapR client setup in the node from where you are executing the test.

```
public class HadoopFileSystemManager {
        private String url;
        public void writeFile(String filePath,String data) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
            System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "/opt/mapr/lib" );
            Path fPath = new Path(filePath);
            String url = url = "hdfs://"+ip+":"+"8020";
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(url),new Configuration());
            System.out.println(fs.getWorkingDirectory());
            FSDataOutputStream writeStream = fs.create(fPath);
            writeStream.writeChars(data);
            writeStream.close();
        }

    }
```

Add the following to the classpath:

> /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-core.jar:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/maprfs-0.1.jar:.:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar

This statement in the above code:  `System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "/opt/mapr/lib" );` can be removed and can be supplied using `-Djava.library.path` too, if you are running your program from terminal when building.

**/opt/mapr** may not be your path to mapr files. If that's the case replace the path accordingly wherever applicable.

**After comment:**
If you are using Maven to build your project, try using the following in the pom.xml,
and with scope provided. MapR is compatible with the normal Apache Hadoop distribution too. So, while building you can use the same. Then when you run your program, you would supply the mapR jars in the classpath.

```
<dependency>
   <groupid>hadoop</groupid>
   <artifactid>hadoop</artifactid>
   <version>0.20.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. May be i have configured the system wrongly.

In the pom.xml of my project ,i have added these two dependencies.
<artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5-alpha</version> and
<artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5-alpha</version> and i figured out from some site that core-site.xml needs to configured also. So i changed to 
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://<ip>:8020</value>.

I am running the test program from my work machine.

Comment: @user608020: can you execute MapR job from you test machine?

Comment: I have created two projects one for Pivotal and one for MapR
1. Mapr pom.xml has hadoop-core (1.0.3-mapr-2.1.2.1) dependency and 
This project only writes to MapR and fails with pivotal

2. Pivotal pom.xml has hadoop-hdfs(2.0.2-alpha) and hadoop-common(2.0.2-alpha) dependency.
This project only writes to Pivotal and fails with MapR.

Same code is used in both the projects.

Please let me know how to write to Pivotal and MapR in a single project.Merging the pom.xml didnt work

Comment: I have no idea about Pivotal, but MapR works with normal Apache Hadoop API (MapR says that) - so when you do scope=provided in the pom.xml, I guess keeping it should work for compilation. When you run, make sure, you use the MapR jars in the classpath.